# Finding videos by resolution in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, video, windows-explorer, resolution

I have hundreds of videos in my hard drive, and I want to delete those that have low resolution to get space free, but I can't find a way to do that.

Googling there are people who says "choose an appropriate column in Explorer view to show the details of the file, like width, height, resolution, or photogram width/height" but in my case those details aren't shown for videos, although it works for images.

Is there a native way to do what I want, or another alternative like software utility or script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right click the top column in your explorer, you will be given a number of details to view.  One of the options should be `More...`

[image]

After clicking that, you should see a large list of things to choose from.

Two properties in particular; `Frame Height` and `Frame Width` are probably what you are looking for.

[image]

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: It's a little bit strange, I've tried this before posting the question, and in the interim also installed a game and updated the DirectX, came back to my question, read the answer, tried again, and vóila, it works! I don't see the relation, but could be a workaround.

Comment: @Alcides Hmm, cant say if their is a connection between the two.  Although, I am happy that it is working nonetheless!